# Fourier transformation of Hann window is wrong

Tags: fourier-analysis

From the documentation

```
f = FourierTransform[HannWindow[x], x, w];
Plot[Log10@Abs[f], {w, -80, 80}, PlotRange -> All]
```

which produces

[image]

Now I was trying to do the same for a discrete case using $1/n$ normalization

```
    T = 1.;
    num = 1000;
    funx = Table[i, {i, -T/2, T/2, T/(num - 1)}];
    funHann = HannWindow /@ (funx/T);
    frek = Most@Range[-num/2, num/2, 1]/T;
    DFT = Fourier[funHann, FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}]~
          RotateRight~(IntegerPart@(num/2));
    ListLogPlot[Transpose[{frek, Abs@DFT}], PlotRange -> All]
```

which instead of produces something totally different
[image]

Does anybody have an idea why?

EDIT:
I think I managed to get to a working case, but not via implemented `Fourier` instead I defined DFT

```
    xfft = With[{N = num - 1}, 
   Compile[{{k, _Real}, {fun1, _Real, 1}}, (1/N)*
     fun1.Exp[-2*Pi*I*Range[0, N - 1]*k/N]]];
frek = Join[Most@Range[0, num/2, 1], Most@Range[-num/2, 0, 1]]/(10.0);
XHann = (xfft[#, Most@funHann]) & /@ (Most@frek);
out = ListLogPlot[{Transpose[{Most@frek, Abs[XHann]}]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, All}, Joined -> {True, True}, 
  Frame -> True, PlotMarkers -> {\[FilledCircle], 6}, Joined -> True, 
  ImageSize -> Large, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Courier New", FontSize -> 10}]
```

[image]

I really don't understand the implemented `Fourier` and what is correct or what is wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have sampled too small a range in x, so you don't have sufficient resolution in frequency space to see the structure. With a larger x range:

```
data = Array[HannWindow, 1024, {-20, 20}];
ListLogPlot[Abs@Fourier[data] ~RotateRight~ 512,
  Joined -> True, DataRange -> {-1, 1} 1024 π/40]
```

[image]

Comment: I have a more theoretical question than. I is obvious from your and my code that the maximum amplitude in the spectrum depends on the range in x. Im not so sure I understand that part. The greater the range, the smaller the amplitude of Main lobe.

Comment: @skrat I faced exactly the same problem recently. I had some peaks in my PSD that would simply disappear when using smaller x intervals.